# Is my ROS environment perfect? or not?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed kinetic in ubuntu16.04, and I did operation check along ROS wiki tutorial.
I did the following command.

```
mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src    
cd ~/catkin_ws/    
catkin_make
```

And I got result.

```
Base path: /home/username/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/username/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/username/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/username/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/username/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/username/catkin_ws/build"    
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/username/catkin_ws/build"
####
```

Is my ROS environment perfect? or not?
Please tell me how to solve. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401610/is-my-ros-environment-perfect?-or-not?/) by [Renox](https://answers.ros.org/users/106378/renox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2022-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's roughly the output expected if `catkin_ws` has no packages in the `src/` directory and you have already run `catkin_make` once before (meaning you already have a `build/` and `devel/` directory created by previous runs of `catkin_make`). It's impossible to say if your ROS environment is "perfect" from this, but I see no obvious issues with the information given.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2022-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-06-01**:
I think OP can also start with using `rosdep` from the beginning

**Comment by [Renox](https://answers.ros.org/users/106378/renox/) on 2022-06-02**:
Thank you for your comments. I could solve.

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-06-02**:
@Renox, if this solves your problem, please consider accepting it.